# Jasmine, React & AJAX: Unit testing function within a function

Tags: javascript, ajax, unit-testing, reactjs, jasmine

Here's the code I would like to test. Specifically, I want to spy on a utility called `Linkvalidation.validate` to make sure that it is called when `handleSave()` is called.

This code lives in a component called the `CondensedFormModal`:

```
handleSave() {
  LinkValidation.validate(this.state.url)
  .then((response) => {
    if (response.success) {
      this.setState({
        message: ''
      });
    }
  })
  .fail((error) => {
    if (error && error.message && error.message.match(/invalid internal link/)) {
      this.setState({
        message: 'The URL is an internal link. Please use a public link.'
      });
    } else {
      this.setState({
        message: 'The URL is invalid.'
      });
    }
  });
```

Here is the LinkValidation.validate utility I'm using in the `handleSave` function above:

```
  define([
  'module/api-call'
  ], function(
  ApiCall
  ) {

  'use strict';

  // Calls validation API
  function validate(link) {
  var deferred = $.Deferred();

  ApiCall.apiCall(
    '/url/check',
    { link: link },
    'POST',
    function(data) {
      if (data.success === true) {
        deferred.resolve(data);
      } else {
        // This link is not valid
        deferred.reject(data);
      }
    },
    function() {
      deferred.reject();
    }
  );

  return deferred;
}

return {
  validate: validate
};
});
```

Here is my test file--

Import statement: 
`import { validate } from 'modules/link-validation.js';`

Test:

```
describe('when the URL is an internal link', () => {
          it('displays a unique error message', (done) => {
            let modal = shallowInstance(<CondensedFormModal />);
            modal.setState({
              url: 'https://internal.example.com'
            });

            let x = jasmine.createSpy('validate').and.returnValue({
              message: "invalid internal link",
              success: false,
              url: 'https://example.com'
            });

            modal.handleSave();
            _.defer(() => {
              expect(x).toHaveBeenCalled();
              done();
            });
          });
   });
```

When I run this test, it consistently fails with the message "Expected spy validate to have been called."

After looking at the Jasmine docs (https://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction) and various other Stack Overflow questions ([Unit test with spy is failing. Says spy was never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140869/unit-test-with-spy-is-failing-says-spy-was-never-called) , [Jasmine test case error 'Spy to have been called'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31634863/jasmine-test-case-error-spy-to-have-been-called) , etc.) I'm unable to make this work. I've also tried `callFake` and `callThrough` instead of `returnValue`.

Any ideas on how to spy on `LinkValidation.validate` to assure that it was called?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
let x = jasmine.createSpy('validate')
```

creates new spy function (it doesn't spy on existing `validate` function) and `handleSave` function is not aware of it. So it's not called at all.
You have to set spy on function that is actually called in your component. Since your `CondensedFormModal` uses `LinkValidation` module (which I assume is imported in component file) you have to set spy on `validate` function from imported module which is actually used by component. So I'd suggest something like this:

1. In `CondensedFormModal` constructor set `LinkValidation` as component property to make it easily accessible in tests:

   ```
   this.LinkValidation = LinkValidation;
   ```
2. In `handleSave` use `validate` function like this:

   ```
   this.LinkValidation.validate(this.state.url);
   ```
3. And finally in test set spy on component `validate` method:

   ```
   describe('when the URL is an internal link', () => {
         it('displays a unique error message', (done) => {
           let modal = shallowInstance(<CondensedFormModal />);
           ...

           spyOn(modal.LinkValidation, 'validate').and.returnValue({
             message: "invalid internal link",
             success: false,
             url: 'https://dash.vagrant.local.rf29.net/shopping/new'
           });

           modal.handleSave();
           _.defer(() => {
             expect(modal.LinkValidation.validate).toHaveBeenCalled();
             done();
           });
         });
    });
   ```